# Disabling vbox services to decrease boot time

Tags: linux, systemd, virtualbox, services

I did a `systemd-analyze critical-chain` at boot on my system, vanilla Arch running on i3wm.

Now, I also have `Virtualbox` installed on my system.  Therefore, the output from `systemd-analyze critical-chain` looks like this:

```
graphical.target @45.620s
└─multi-user.target @45.620s
  └─vboxweb-service.service @45.609s +10ms
    └─vboxdrv.service @1.645s +43.956s
      └─basic.target @1.637s
        └─sockets.target @1.637s
          └─dbus.socket @1.637s
            └─sysinit.target @1.637s
              └─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount @6.422s +3ms
                └─systemd-modules-load.service @348ms +36ms
                  └─systemd-journald.socket @340ms
                    └─system.slice @327ms
                      └─-.slice @327ms
```

Note that `vboxdrv.service' takes the longest time, around 43 seconds, which is almost 90% of the total boot time.

My question is:  Is it safe to disable both of these services with: `systemd disable vboxdrv.service`? Then, say whenever I want to run virtualbox, I can just do: `systemd start vboxdrv.service`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to.

`vboxdrv.service` recompiles kernel drivers only when you update your kernel which I'm pretty sure you don't do daily. Still you can disable it.

Answer (score 3):

The `systemd disable vboxdrv.service` command did not work for me.

To disable and enable the vboxdrv, I used the following commands:

```
systemctl disable vboxdrv.service
systemctl enable vboxdrv.service
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to reducing startup time, if you want to have fewer processes running, yes you can to stop and disable the virtualbox's services:

```
systemctl stop vboxweb-service.service vboxballoonctrl-service.service vboxdrv.service
systemctl disable vboxweb-service.service vboxballoonctrl-service.service vboxdrv.service
```

So you just need to start these services before when need to use VMs.
But I tested and see it still continues to start again when reboot the system.